# If $P$ is the intersection of the altitudes of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ and $r$ is the circumradius, then $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2=4r^2$

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, solid-geometry

Prove that, if $P$ is the intersection of the altitudes of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ and $r$ is the circumradius, then $$PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2=4r^2$$

Comment: In a tetrahedron, the altitudes may not meet. Is youir question about (i) "equilateral" tetrahedrons (all side lengths equal, all faces equilateral triangles, or (ii) the subcollection of all tetrahedrons for which the four altitudes meet at a common point $P$, or (iii) some other class of tetrahedrons included in (ii) but not all of (ii)?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then I'd go for II. Suppose they have a common point $P$.

Comment: It's simplified by assuming regular tetrahedron rather than considering if they meet.

Comment: when P is the common point, it means P is the center of the sphere. then PA=PB=PC=PD=r so there is nothing to proof.

Comment: Only for a regular tetrahedron is $P$ the center of the sphere. (I guess @chenbai knew this, and was responding to user1709828's comment, but it should be emphasized that the problem is really about more general tetrahedra.)

Answer (score 6):

An orthocentric tetrahedron is by definition any tetrahedron for which the altitudes meet at a point, and that point is called the orthocenter of the tetrahedron. I use a fact relating the orthocenter, the circumcenter, and the centroid which holds for any orthocentric tetrahedron. Reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron

Let $P$ be the orthocenter, $K$ be the centroid $(A+B+C+D)/4$, and $O$ be the circumcenter. The relation between these points is that $P$ is the symmetric point to $O$ with respect to $K$, i.e. that $K$ is the midpoint of segment $PO$. The squared length of any segment $XY$ between points $X,Y$ in 3-space is the dot product $(X-Y)\cdot(X-Y)$, viewing the points $X,Y$ as vectors based at the origin. We will write $(X-Y)^2$ for this dot product, so that the relation between $P,K,O$ mentioned above implies that
$$[1]\ \ \ \ (P-K)^2-(O-K)^2=0.$$
Now the squared lengths $PA^2$ etc. are $(P-A)^2$ etc. in our dot product notation. The relation
$$PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2-4r^2=0$$ becomes in our notation, since $r^2=(O-A)^2=...=(O-D)^2,$
$$[2]\ \ \ \ (P-A)^2+(P-B)^2+(P-C)^2+(P-D)^2\\ -(O-A)^2-(O-B)^2-(O-C)^2-(O-D)^2=0.$$
When the dot products are all multiplied out, it turns out that the expression on the left of [2] is (surprisingly, at least to me) exactly 4 times the expression on the left of [1]. So since [1] is a known fact about orthocentric tetrahedra, it follows that [2] also holds, finishing the proof.

Answer (score 4):

This is a supplement to coffeemath's answer. It is a pity to let the amazing facts metioned there leave as a mystery.

Let $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \vec{x}_3, \vec{x}_4$ be the vertices of a non-degenerate tetrahedron. WOLOG, we will pick the circumcenter of the tetrahedron as the origin.
We have $|\vec{x}_1| = |\vec{x}_2| = |\vec{x}_3| = |\vec{x}_4| = r$, the circumradius.
Let us also assume the four altitudes intersect at a single point $\vec{p}$.

The vector $\vec{x}_1 - \vec{p}$ is in the direction of the normal vector for the affine plane $\langle x_2x_3x_4\rangle$ generated by the 3 vectors
$\vec{x}_2$, $\vec{x}_3$ and $\vec{x}_4$. This means it will be perpendicular to every vector that lives in the plane. In particular, the vector $\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4$, i.e.

$$(\vec{x}_1 - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0\tag{*1a}$$

By a similar argument to $\vec{x}_2 - \vec{p}$ and the affine plane $\langle x_4x_3x_1\rangle$, we get:

$$(\vec{x}_2 - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0\tag{*1b}$$

Now

$$(*1a) - (*1b) \implies (\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_2) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0$$

i.e. the pair of opposite edges $\langle x_1x_2 \rangle$ and $\langle x_3x_4\rangle$ are perpendicular to each other. By a similar argument, the other two pairs of opposite edges,
$\{ \langle x_1x_3\rangle$, $\langle x_2x_4\rangle \}$ and $\{ \langle x_1x_4\rangle$, $\langle x_2x_3\rangle \}$ are perpendicular among themselves. This means the tetrahedron
is an orthocentric tetrahedron as described in coffeemath's answer.

Next,
$$(*1a) + (*1b) \implies (\frac{\vec{x}_1 + \vec{x}_2}{2} - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0\tag{*2a}$$
Notice
$$(\vec{x}_3 + \vec{x}_4) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = |\vec{x}_3|^2 - |\vec{x}_4|^2 = r^2 - r^2 = 0\tag{*2b}$$
$(*2a) + \frac12 (*2b)$ then gives us:
$$(2 \vec{c} - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0$$

where $\vec{c} = \frac{\vec{x}_1 + \vec{x}_2 + \vec{x}_3 + \vec{x}_4}{4}$ is the centroid of the tetrahedron. By a similar argument, we have:

$$(2 \vec{c} - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_4) = 
  (2 \vec{c} - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_4) =
  (2 \vec{c} - \vec{p}) \cdot (\vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4) = 0$$

For a non-degenerate tetrahedron, the 3 vectors $\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_4, \vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_4, \vec{x}_3 - \vec{x}_4$ froms a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
As a result, we get

$$2\vec{c} - \vec{p} = \vec{0} \iff \vec{p} = 2 \vec{c} \iff  \vec{c} = \frac12 ( \vec{p} + \vec{0} )$$

This means the centroid $\vec{c}$ is located at the mid-point between the orthocenter $\vec{p}$ and the circumcenter $\vec{0}$.

Finally, we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 |\vec{x_i} - \vec{p}|^2 
=\sum_{i=1}^4 |\vec{x}_i|^2 - 2 ( \sum_{i=1}^4 \vec{x}_i ) \cdot \vec{p} + 4|\vec{p}|^2
=4 r^2 + 4 \vec{p}\cdot(\vec{p} - 2\vec{c}) = 4 r^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem splits into two logically independent theorems.

1. For *any* point $P$ and *any* other $n$ points $A,B,C,D,(E,F,G,...)$ on a sphere with center $Q$ and radius $r$, the equation $PA^2 + PB^2 + \dots= nr^2$ is equivalent to $PM^2=QM^2$ where $M$ is the center of mass of the $n$ points.  Proof:   the moments of inertia of the $n$ points are the same relative to $P$ and to $Q$.  This is a general algebraic fact about sets of points on spheres, in Euclidean space of any dimension.  For the problem at hand, it means we should prove $|PM|=|QM|$.
2. In an orthocentric tetrahedron, $M$ is the midpoint of $PQ$ (the centroid is half-way between the orthocenter and the circumcenter).  Starting from the first fact about points on spheres, and looking for a reason why this problem is correct, you could guess that $PM=QM$ holds with the points collinear, based on analogy with the Euler line in a triangle.  A proof can be found in Nathan Althshiller-Court's article *Notes On the Orthcentric Tetrahedron* from 1934, which is available in several online forms.

For a general tetrahedron take $P$ to be the Monge point.  Then the formula and both parts of the theorem are true, and $P$ coincides with the orthocenter when one exists.